# Designing a 2-bit ALU

Tags: alu

I want to design a 2-bit ALU that does XOR, OR, AND, and addition.
With help of Wikipedia:

[image]

I designed this:

[image]

However, it's not working.
I tried connecting the controllers to S0, S1, S2 but no difference...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "It's not working" is very vague. Where did you build it? In a Simulator or on a bread board? What exactly, isn't working?

Comment: @Tyler In a Simulator(circuitmaker), you can see it in the photo! Nothing's working. when I change the value of inputs nothing changes, not in AND, OR, XOR and Addition

Comment: If "nothing's working" then the simulator is broken, or you haven't connected things properly, or you aren't using it correctly. How can we possibly diagnose your problem from a low-resolution graphic of your schematic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you need to connect your opcode switches (V1, V2, V3) to the select inputs (A, B and C on the top diagram, S0, S1 and S2 on yours) of the muxes. Also, you need to pull the enable (E pin) low on each of the muxes.